# Does Quickly have an IDE of some sort?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I know quickly is supposed to make life easier for developers of all kinds, I'm just curious as to if there is an IDE for quickly (something like QtCreator or Monodevelop)?

If not, as a part B, is there one on the way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is no.

A `quickly edit` command will open all python files in your default editor. You can however use your preferred editor or IDE for development.

Comment: :( - some day I hope that I get a surprise in one of my curiosity questions :/

Answer (score 6):

Hope my answer comes on time, I just tested and you can use PyDev from eclipse.

Basically you first need to create your Quickly application as shown in the examples, then create a project in [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) (I used the same name) and set the location of your Quickly application as the project location. To be able to launch the project from Eclipse, rename the executable script called  in the bin/ folder to something like *_launcher.py* (the name must differ from the module with the rest of the code).

Now, one nasty piece of work is to make the schema settings work ([a bug about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/976817) is filed). First, to move automatic compiling from the *quickly run* script to *_launcher.py* append this code to the end of the file, right before the *import*  command:

```
### BEGIN inserted from Quickly's run.py
# Compile schema if present
schemapath = os.path.abspath("data/glib-2.0/schemas")
if os.path.exists(schemapath):
    subprocess.call(["glib-compile-schemas", schemapath])
### END
```

Then to tell the application to look for schemas locally as well you have to edit the PyDev launch configuration and in the Environment tab add a variable XDG_DATA_DIRS with a value

*/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/path/to/your/project/**data***

(adjust to match your project path)

You'll be able to modify any files and test if it works and even debug the program, and you can still use normal commands from quickly.

In my case, I already had the bazaar plugin installed in the eclipse enviromnent and I can see which files I need to commit and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Following the bug report in the post by jmolinaso above there now seems to be an even easier way to run your Quickly application from the command line and set the ./bin/APPNAME file as the Main Debug file in Wing IDE.

If had trouble reading the notation in [Patch for bug 976817](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/101963642/976817-schemas.patch) then this is a way to look at it: In your shiny folder you have a "bin" folder, with only one file with your application name. We can call it /bin/APPNAME. In the file APPNAME you need to add a couple of lines between: `sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY)` and:  `if python_path:`

The lines to be included are marked with a `+` in the patch mentioned above.

So just copy paste as follows:

After: `sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY)` add:

```
    datadir = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY, "data")
    if 'XDG_DATA_DIRS' in os.environ:
        os.putenv('XDG_DATA_DIRS', "%s:%s" % (datadir, os.getenv('XDG_DATA_DIRS', '')))
    else:
        os.putenv('XDG_DATA_DIRS', datadir)
```

Leave the orignal:  `if python_path:` and what follows, where it is. Also, please note the indents above, this should be indented with four spaces).

Now you can start your application from the command line, set ./bin/APPNAME as the main debug file in WingIDE (or any other IDE I suppose) and work with you Quickly app as you would with any other application, start/stopping the debugger from WingIDE, for instance. `Quickly run` will also still work from the command line.