# Can I use aptana with Quickly?

Tags: python, quickly, application-development

I want to develop python apps with aptana, I really love this editor.

Is possible to develop python apps with quickly + aptana or only quickly + gedit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quickly respects the $EDITOR variable, so if you set your editor to be Aptana then `quickly edit` will just fire that up for you.

There is also an environment variable just for this:

```
export QUICKLY_EDITOR=aptana
```

Then do `quickly edit &` to fire up your editor and keep the command line open for your next steps.

You can add QUICKLY_EDITOR to your `~/.bashrc` file if you want to keep it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29187/does-quickly-have-an-ide-of-some-sort/101563#101563) to a similar question about configuring Quickly projects to work with Eclipse.