# Quickly with Python 3 *or* how to start a quickly app without quickly run

Tags: application-development, quickly

since Ubuntu 12.10 ships only Python 3 by default, I wanted to ask, what steps should be taken to get my »Quickly« application ready for python 3?

I already know about `2to3`, but I don't know how to start quickly's `quickly run` command with python 3 support *or* how to run my applicaton without quickly. Actually right now I use quickly merely to start my application, because I could'nt figure out how to run a quickly application without `quickly run`.

I appreciate every answer!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 does NOT only ship Python 3! It ships also python 2.7 and python 2.7 is also the default python.

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment (I noticed that too). Anyhow, I managed to port my existing code over to python 3 nonetheless and will write a blog post or something on what I needed to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Port Quickly Python 2.7 to Python 3.x

I am not sure if it was there before I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 but now is a `bin/<programname>` Folder inside the quickly-template code. E.g. `<programname>/bin/<programname>`. It's the entry point from where the quickly app is started!

In this file it's simple to change the python version: Modifying the first line is enough, e.g. change it from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and your quickly application is running with python 3! Of course, you'll still have to modify all the project files to work with python 3 instead of python 2.7. I went the manual route and fixed all upcoming bugs, however, tools like `2to3` could potentially aid you.

### How to start a quickly application without quickly?

Well it's as simple as running `python bin/<programname` from your application's folder (the same python file you need to modify for python 3 compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your question: "How to make you application run without `quickly run`" is  [discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29187/does-quickly-have-an-ide-of-some-sort). The patch to enable that is available as part of the bug report on the issue: [Compiling schemas not part of the application template](https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/976817)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I was already successful in porting it, so I'll leave my answer here, too.

Comment: To apply the patch to your project, download it and run `patch bin/projectname 976817-schemas.patch` where `projectname` is the name of your project, and `976817-schemas.patch` is the name of the patch file you downloaded.